# Measuring absolute time taken by a process

Tags: c++, windows, performance

I am measuring time taken by my process using

`QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency`. It works fine.

As my system is a single processor based system. So many process sharing it.Is it possible to measure CPU time allotted to my process. SO that i can measure absolute time taken.

Platform : Windows
Language : C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223(VS.85).aspx) is probably the call you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use a profiler to measure the time?